# Find the derivative of a piecewise constant function

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I want to differentiate the given function:

\begin{equation}
 f(x)=   \begin{cases}1 \ \ \ \ \ x\in[0,1] \\
 0 \ \ \ \ \ \ x\not\in[0,1] 
            \end{cases}
\end{equation}

However, the simple $f'(x)=0$ seems a little bit too simple, since this is  similar to the Dirac delta function, just stretched over the interval $[0,1]$ instead of at $x=0$.

So I tried to represent the function as a generalized function,

$$f(x)=\int_0^1\delta(x)\phi(x)\text{d}x,$$ where $\phi(x)$ is a locally summable function, infinitely differentiable, $\in C^\infty$.

and use the differentiation rule $$(D^\alpha f,\phi)=(-1)^{|\alpha|}(f,D^{\alpha}\phi),$$ with $\alpha=1$:

$$(D^1 f,\phi)=(-1)^{|1|}(\delta(x),D^{1}\phi)$$

$$(D^1 f,\phi)=-1(\delta(x),\phi'(x))$$

However, I am not sure how to continue. Any hints?

Thanks

Comment: From Wolfram research: [The fundamental Theorem of Calculus applies when f(x) is continuous:](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FundamentalTheoremsofCalculus.html);  with your question, f(x) is **not continuous**, which is problematic for taking a derivative of f(x) in your application.  The [delta function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DeltaFunction.html#:~:text=The%20delta%20function%20is%20a,Language%20as%20DiracDelta%5Bx%5D.) is: "The delta function can be viewed as the derivative of the Heaviside step function", which is different than the function you have since H(x=0)=0.5, again a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exact answer to this question is actually as follows. I was corrected by my Professor, and this is apparently the right procedure.

\begin{equation}
 f(x)=   \begin{cases}1 \ \ \ \ \ x\in[0,1] \\
 0 \ \ \ \ \ \ x\not\in[0,1] 
            \end{cases}
\end{equation}

We use the formula

$$(f',\phi) = -(f,\phi') = -\int_\mathbb{R} f\phi' dx = -\int_{-\infty}^{x_1}f\phi' dx - \int_{x_1}^{x_2}f\phi' dx - \cdots -\int_{x_m}^{\infty}f\phi' dx $$

where $x_1=0$ and $x_2=1$, hence we obtain

$$(f',\phi) = -(f,\phi') = -\int_\mathbb{R} f\phi' dx = -\int_{-\infty}^{0}f\phi' dx - \int_{0}^{1}f\phi' dx - \int_{1}^{\infty}f\phi' dx $$

Now using integration by parts for each term, we get:

$$(f',\phi)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{df}{dx}\phi(x) dx + \sum_{j=1}^m [f(x_{j^+})-f(x{_j^-})]\phi(x_j)=$$

We have that $m=2$ so we obtain
$$=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{df}{dx}\phi(x) dx +  [f(x{_1^+})-f(x{_1^-})]\phi(x_1)+ [f(x{_2^+})-f(x{_2^-})]\phi(x_2)$$
which is
$$=  [f(0^+)-f(0^-)]\phi(0)+ [f(1^+)-f(1^-)]\phi(1)$$

which gives, since $\delta(x)$ is normally centered at $x=0$ hence, with $\phi(1)=\delta(x-1)$, we obtain
$$(f',\phi)=\delta(x)+ \delta(x-1)$$

Note that this is only possible since $\phi(x) \in \mathscr{L}_{loc}^\infty \to \delta(x)$ as $k\to \infty \in \mathbb{R}$, which is satisfied in the given space of the function.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that just from the definition of the derivative, $f'(x) = 0$ for all $x\neq 0, 1$. In particular, for any $φ\in C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R})$,
$$0 = \int φ(x)f'(x) dx = -\int φ'(x)f(x) dx = -\int_0^1 φ'(x) dx.$$
Choosing any test function $φ$ such that the last integral is nonzero (there are plenty such functions) gives a contradiction. Hence $f$ is not (weakly) differentiable.

Comment: I took the $f(x) = \mathbb{1}_{[0;1]}(x)$ you have given in your post; the function itself has nothing to do with Dirac deltas.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot for your answer.